# Vector not declared in scope error

Tags: c++, vector, scope, declaration

When doing the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace std;

std::vector<double> getPosVector(string path) {
  const char *dir = path.c_str();
  struct dirent *dp;
  DIR *fd;
  int count = 0;
  std::vector<double> myvector;

  if ((fd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "listdir: can't open %s\n", dir);
    return myvector;
  }

  while ((dp = readdir(fd)) != NULL) {
    if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
      continue;    /* skip self and parent */

    // Load image as matrix, keep directory
    string currentImage = path+'/'+dp->d_name;

   // Load image
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread(currentImage.c_str(),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(!image.data) {
      cout << "Could not load image file: " << endl;
   }    


   // Find image dimensions
   int rows = image.rows; 
   int cols = image.cols;
   double s = cv::sum(image)[0];
   double mean = s/(rows*cols);
   myvector.push_back(mean);

  }
closedir(fd);
return myvector;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Check argument
  if(argc<3) {
    cout << "Usage: CRForest-Detector.exe mode [config.txt] [tree_offset]" << endl;
    cout << "mode: 0 - train; 1 - show; 2 - detect" << endl;
    cout << "tree_offset: output number for trees" << endl;
    cout << "Load default: mode - 2" << endl; 
} else

  std::vector<double> pos_vector = getPosVector(argv[1]);
  cout << pos_vector.size() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I am getting this message:

```
getThreshold.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
getThreshold.cpp:130:22: error: ‘pos_vector’ was not declared in this scope
      cout << int(pos_vector.size()) << endl;
                  ^
make: *** [getThreshold.o] Error 1
```

I have looked far and wide for a solution but I must not be doing that right. Thanks for your help.

My makefile looks like this (i am on linux and using g++):

```
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/opencv
LIBS = -lcxcore -lcv -lcvaux -lhighgui -lml
LIBDIRS = -L/usr/local/lib

OPT = -O3 -Wno-deprecated

CC=g++

.PHONY: all clean

OBJS = getThreshold.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~ getThreshold

all:    getThreshold
        echo all: make complete
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(INCLUDES) $+ $(OPT) `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`

getThreshold: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $+ $(OPT) `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: runs fine for me. I noticed this is on line 130, so you clearly left out some things. Also, what does your makefile look like. You also don't have to cast .size()

Comment: Thanks Ben. I didn't want to make this post verbose but I am sure that the bit of code omitted works fine as it behaves as expected during testing.

Comment: The code as posted can't have that error. You need to post at least enough code to actually reproduce the error.

Comment: Is `pos_vector` declared inside of a compound statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The code you're showing us doesn't produce the error you're showing us.  Please [edit] your question [to these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just found out that I was missing parentheses for the else part in main...thanks for your help anyhow!! It was a useful first post for me in as much as I learnt the proper way to submit a query here. Cheers!